# web2py-how to convert a list object to a 2D array or render it in google.visualization.arrayToDataTable

Tags: list, charts, google-visualization, web2py

I can't get to iterate through my list object arData = [] which has, 
['yesterday', 42, 49], ['Today', 50, 67], ['Tommorro', 57, 63]...]
to display the chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string','Day');
    data.addColumn('number','Positive');
    data.addColumn('number','Negative');
    data.addRows([{{=arData}}]
    );...
</script>
```

i also tried this

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    {{for row in arData:}}
            {{arData[i]}}
    {{pass}}
    );
```

and

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{=arData}});
```

the variable i and arData are from a function dict return

please help and some best pratice

Comment: When you view the html source when this page is rendered, how does your data.addRows statement look?

Comment: The data.addRows statement is actually empty i.e, data.addRows([                  ]);

Comment: Are you sure `arData` has data? I can put the following into a view and it works for me. controllers/default.py controller: `def test1(): return dict()` views/default/test1.html: `{{arData = [['yesterday', 42, 49], ['Today', 50, 67], ['Tommorro', 57, 63]] }}
data.addRows([{{=arData}}]` Can you try making a simple test example like that to see if it works?

Comment: It doesn't work! try also initialize `arData` in the controllers/default.py controller: `def test1():   arData = [['yesterday', 42, 49], ['Today', 50, 67], ['Tommorro', 57, 63]] return dict(arData=arData)` views/default/test1.html:  `data.addRows([{{=arData}}]);`

Comment: Does a simple "hello world" string work?

Comment: Yes, it works.Do you mean `data.addRows([
  ['Today', 14, 96]]);`
? In the previous comment, does defining the arData in the controller rather than in the view work for you?

Comment: Yes I tried defining it in the controller and it works.  Full controller code: `def test1():
    arData = [['yesterday', 42, 49], ['Today', 50, 67], ['Tommorro', 57, 63]]
    return dict(arData=arData)` And full view code: `{{extend 'layout.html'}}
data.addRows({{=arData}})`

Comment: When I view the html source when this page is rendered, `data.addRows([[&#x27;Day&#x27;, &#x27;Positive&#x27;, &#x27;Negative&#x27;], [&#x27;24th&#x27;, 191, 148], [&#x27;25th&#x27;, 157, 85], [&#x27;26th&#x27;, 122, 111], [&#x27;27th&#x27;, 181, 92], [&#x27;28th&#x27;, 134, 59], [&#x27;29th&#x27;, 113, 44], [&#x27;30th&#x27;, 107, 99], [&#x27;31th&#x27;, 39, 47]]);`

Comment: I would try asking your question on the official web2py google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py